# PHP Regex - How to do str_replace on preg_replace numeric backreferences?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I had the following PHP Regex code, to replace all emails with a "[removed email]" replacement string; and it worked nicely:

```
$pattern = "/[^@\s]*@[^@\s]*\.[^@\s]*/"; 
$replacement = "[removed email]";
$body_highlighted = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $body_highlighted);
```

However, the email replacement strategy changed and now I need to actually show the emails but replace certain parts of it. I wanted to use str_replace on the numeric backreferences, like this, but it doesn't work.

```
$pattern = "/[^@\s]*@[^@\s]*\.[^@\s]*/"; 
$email_part = "$0";
$replacement = str_replace('a','b', $email_part); // replace all letter A with B in each email
$body_highlighted = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $body_highlighted);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `str_replace` runs at calling, not as a binding. There is no `a` in `$0` so it remains unchanged. Likely you want to be using `preg_replace_callback`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `str_replace` on the actual string `$0` and not the backreference it references, which is why it's not working.

You want to do the str_replace while you are doing the `preg_replace`, so you can use `preg_replace_callback` to use a callback function to get the "email part" and perform the string manipulation on it during the regex replacement.

**To extract the first part of the email (before the '@') and change it:**

```
$pattern = "/([^@\s]*)(@[^@\s]*\.[^@\s]*)/"; 
$body_highlighted = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'change_email', $body_highlighted);

/* str_replace the first matching part on the email */
function change_email($matches){
  return str_replace('a','b', $matches[1]).$matches[2];
}
```

If you used this with, for example: 
`$body_highlighted = "My email is aaaazz@gmail.com";` 
the result: `My email is bbbbzz@gmail.com`

Note the changes to the regex in `$pattern` to split the email in two parts - before `@` and the part include `@` and the domain name. These are accessed in the callback function as `$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]`.

**If you want to access the domain part of the email address (after the `@`):**

You can split the email into 3 parts (before `@`, the `@` and everything after the `@`) you can use the following:

```
$pattern = "/([^@\s]*)(@)([^@\s]*\.[^@\s]*)/"; 
$body_highlighted = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'change_email', $body_highlighted);

function change_email($matches){
  return str_replace('a','b', $matches[1]).$matches[2].str_replace('y','z', $matches[3]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and expertise. This is exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated.